# Ghostscript with a Zebra ZM600

Tags: printing, ghostscript

I have created a program which takes a PDF and prints it using Ghostscript.NET.
The printer in question is a Zebra ZM600, and the printing works fine. However I would like to do some adjustments to the labels, and this can be done using the driver. When I print using Adobe Reader, the adjustments work, but when I use the program which I have created to print the file, it seems like GhostScript.NET does something with the properties as this doesn't work at all (it is printed but the adjustments doesn't work).

```
        using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new GhostscriptProcessor())
        {
            List<string> switches = new List<string>();
            switches.Add("-empty");
            switches.Add("-dPrinted");
            switches.Add("-dBATCH");
            switches.Add("-dNoCancel");
            switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
            switches.Add("-dNOSAFER");
            switches.Add("-dNumCopies=1");
            switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2");
            switches.Add("-sOutputFile=%printer%" + printerName);
            switches.Add("-f");
            switches.Add(path);
            processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null);
            _logger.Info("After starting process");
        }
```

The question is, does anybody know if there is a way to force Ghostscript to use the adjustments on the printer driver? Or if there are any better alternatives for printing PDFs on a label printer?

Comment: You aren't at all specific about what 'adjustments' you mean, which makes it pretty much impossible to help you (also you've tagged this with Ghostscript instead of Ghostscript.NET). If you are trying to run this silently then you need to be aware that Ghostscript (more accurately, the Ghostscript mswinpr2 device) uses the printer defaults when you do that. If you want to use the current printer configuration instead of the default configuration then you need to have the printer dialog appear.

Comment: Adjustments in this case is shifting, to the right or left, up and down. The point is that when you create these "printer defaults" and use them from Adobe, everything works fine, but when you do it from "Ghostscript" it doesn't.

Comment: Pretty much impossible to diagnose without the printer driver at the very least. Have you tried this by leaving off the OutputFile and -dNoCancel ? That will produce the printer chooser dialog, select the printer you want and try that.  If that works, then the answer is what I mentioned above; the printer defaults are different to the current configuration and the mswinpr2 device uses the defaults if you run it that way. If it makes no difference choosing the printer from the dialog (and make sure you check the configuration) then frankly I have no clue.